# Using variables in javascript to reference html elements dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables

I am trying to use jQuery / javascript to remove a class from a named input element if a checkbox is ticked.

I have several checkboxes, each with a accompanying hidden (on page load) text input field.

The checkbox and text input field are named "question_X" and "question_X_description" respectively. (where X is a number 0 to 100, say)

As such I'm trying to define a variable in my code that is defined as "this element's name"+"_description", and then use that to define the suitable element to remove the class from.

Here is what I've tried:

```
$('input:checkbox').change(function(){

var x = $(this).attr('name').'_description';

if($(this).is(":checked")) {
    $('input[name="x"]').removeClass("hidden");
} else {
     $('input[name="x"]').addClass("hidden");
}
});
```

However, nothing happens when the any checkbox is checked. Am I referencing my variable correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use your console, It will have error messages.

**First issue**

```
var x = $(this).attr('name').'_description';
                           ^^^
```

That is not how you build a string in JavaScript. JavaScript does not use `.` to join strings. It uses `+`

```
var x = $(this).attr('name') + '_description';
```

**Second issue**

```
$('input[name="x"]').
```

You are not looking for the string you built, you are looking for an element with the name x

Needs to be

```
$('input[name="' + x + '"]').
```

Comment: Thanks kind viking man: I am not good at javascript :) Thanks for teaching me how to reference my variables properly and concatenate! I'll accept once the time limit runs down.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input[name="x"]').removeClass("hidden");
```

Will be looking for:

```
<input name="x" />
```

Try

```
$(name="'+x+'").removeClass("hidden");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `document.getElementById('element_name')`

Example of HTML element:
`<input type="text" id="element_name">`